# Search provided by Google vs custom results order

Tags: sorting, search, google-custom-search

I want to use google custom search on my site - it's indexed anyway, and the search engine Google provides saves me a lot of pain re-implementing the things they alredy have.

Only problem I have is - I need the results sorted my way: I got number of articles on my site, each having a 'rank'. And those that match the search query I want to show in order - sorted by their rank.

Is it possible to do that, using google's custom search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that the answer to your question is no. Custom Search is really just a skinnable site:yourdomain.com that you can embed on your pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, checkout:
http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/ranking.html